# Como criar uma lista de datas do ano em php, pulando os finais de semana?

Tags: php, data

Preciso criar uma lista de datas em PHP, onde eu listarei todas as datas, desde o primeiro dia do ano, até o último. Porém, nessa lista, datas referentes ao final de semana (sábado e domingo) devem ser puladas.

Exemplo:

```
01/02/2016 => Segunda
02/02/2016 => Terça
03/02/2016 => Quarta
04/02/2016 => Quinta
05/02/2016 => Sexta
08/02/2016 => Segunda
```

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso em php?

Comment: Downvoter, o que pode ser feito para melhorar a pergunta?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode usar classe DatePeriod para montar o periodo de tempo desejado, no exemplo utilizei o mês de fevereiro, para saber quais dias são finais de semana(sabádo e domingo) o inglês da uma ajuda, pois ambos os dias começam com S(saturday e sunday), basta saber se o dia semana começa com S ou não.

```
$inicio = new DateTime('2016-02-01');
$fim = new DateTime('2016-02-29');

$periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, new DateInterval('P1D'), $fim);
$validos = [];
foreach($periodo as $item){

    if(substr($item->format("D"), 0, 1) != 'S'){
        $validos[] = $item->format('d/m/Y');
    }
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($validos);
```

Sáida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01/02/2016
    [1] => 02/02/2016
    [2] => 03/02/2016
    [3] => 04/02/2016
    [4] => 05/02/2016
    [5] => 08/02/2016
    [6] => 09/02/2016
    [7] => 10/02/2016
    [8] => 11/02/2016
    [9] => 12/02/2016
    [10] => 15/02/2016
    [11] => 16/02/2016
    [12] => 17/02/2016
    [13] => 18/02/2016
    [14] => 19/02/2016
    [15] => 22/02/2016
    [16] => 23/02/2016
    [17] => 24/02/2016
    [18] => 25/02/2016
    [19] => 26/02/2016
)
```

Comment: Gostou do `CallbackFilterIterator`? Nunca vi ninguém usando ele!

Comment: Legal, interessante é que o `S` só tem em `Saturday` e `Sunday`. Eu gosto das coisas bem explicadinhas, no seus míiiiiinimos detalhes.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Nem lembrei do número do dia da semana(0 e 6), eu já vi alguem usando :D

Comment: A única coisa que não gostei é que `DatePeriod` deveria implementar `Iterator`. O PHP pecou nisso aí, mas ainda bem que dá pra corrigir. Só que minha resposta ficou parecendo java (por causa do excesso de instâncias).

Comment: Vou marcar a resposta depois, só pra ver se alguém consegue fazer isso sem orientação a objetos, rsrsrsrs.

Answer (score 4):

Já temos várias respostas, mas lá vai mais uma maneira, em "versão compacta":

```
$year = 2016;

for( $d = mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year ); date( 'Y', $d ) == $year; $d += 86400 )
    date( 'N', $d ) < 6 ? $lista[] = date( 'd/m/Y', $d ) : $d += 86400;
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/SRbcbV)**.

**Funcionamento:**

- `$d = mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year )` cria um *timestamp* do primeiro dia do ano desejado
- `date( 'Y', $d ) == $year` faz com que o loop permaneça apenas no ano desejado
- `$d += 86400` adiciona um dia ao *timestamp* (86400 = 24 * 60 * 60 segundos).
- `date( 'N', $d ) < 6` verifica se é dia útil
- se for, `$lista[] = date( 'd/m/Y', $d )` adiciona a data à lista.
- se não, `$d += 86400` já pula o domingo pra "economizar *loop*" (poderia deixar sem isso).

Comment: Aqui tem uma versão no formato `[01/01/2016] => Sexta`: http://ideone.com/fVDarR

Answer (score 3):

Eu tenho uma solução também, e é quase parecida com a resposta do @rray, porém com algumas variações e explicações a respeito dos `Iterators` utilizados.

Vamos lá:

```
// Defini a data inicial como 01/01 do ano atual

$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', '01-01');

$endDate = clone $startDate;

// Modifico o clone colocando para o ano que vem

$endDate->modify('+1 year');


// Adiciona um intervaldo de 1 em 1 dia

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day');

// Criamos um objeto DatePeriod, que também é um iterator

$period = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate);

// Passo DatePeriod para argumento de IteratorIterator
// Faço isso pois DatePeriod implementa Traversable, 
// que não é aceita por callbackFilterIterator 
// (que aceita uma implementação de Iterator como parâmetro)
// Então nesse caso, IteratorIterator aceita Traversable. 
// E CallbackFilterIterator aceita Iterator (que é implementado por IteratorIterator)

$iterablePeriod = new IteratorIterator($period);


// Utilizo esse Iterator para filtrar o outro DatePeriod, ignorando sábados e domíngos


$iterator = new CallbackFilterIterator($iterablePeriod, function ($date)
{
    $week = $date->format('w');

    return $week != '0' && $week != '6';
});


// No final posso transformar num `array` de objetos Datetime
```

// Ou iterar `$iterator` através do `foreach`
    print_r(iterator_to_array($iterator));

Comment: Sim, eu sei, esse código ficou parecendo java.

Comment: Isso aí está parecendo Java

Answer (score 3):

eu faria assim

```
<?php
$diasDaSemana = array(
    1=>'Segunda',
    2=>'Terça',
    3=>'Quarta',
    4=>'Quinta',
    5=>'Sexta',
);
$inicio = DateTime::CreateFromFormat("d-m",'01-01');

$fim = clone $inicio;
$fim->modify('+1 year');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($inicio, $interval ,$fim);
foreach ($daterange as $date){

  if($date->format('w') !=0 && $date->format('w') !=6 ){
    $arrayDatas[] =  $date;
  }

  //ou pra ficar como no seu exemplo
  if($date->format('w') !=0 && $date->format('w') !=6 ){
    $array[$date->format('d-m-Y')] =  $diasDaSemana[$date->format('w')];
  }
}
  echo "<pre>\n";
  var_dump($arrayDatas);
  echo "</pre>\n";

  echo "<pre>\n";
  var_export($array);
  echo "</pre>\n";
```