# PHP Verifica Fins de Semanas e Feriados

Tags: php

Eu preciso de uma função em PHP que que me retorne se é feriado nacional ou fim de semana, alguem tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Não existe tal função. Verificar feriado é complicado. Tem que ter uma banco de dados com todos, mesmo assim pode mudar.

Comment: Feriado nacional é impossível de representar nativamente.

Comment: [Como criar uma lista de datas do ano em php, pulando os finais de semana?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111656/91)

Comment: [Script de dias úteis](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61369/91)

Answer (score 4):

Não há função nativa para isso, mas você pode usar o Holiday API, ele suporta feriados do Brasil e de outras localidades, *Portugal não é suportado por enquanto*.

**Para demonstração fiz este JavaScript:**

```js
$(':button').click(function() {
  var dia = $(':input[dia]').val();
  var mes = $(':input[mes]').val();
  var ano = $(':input[ano]').val();
  var pais = $(':input[pais]').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?country=' + pais + '&year=' + ano + '&month=' + mes + '&day=' + dia,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data.holidays[0] != null ? data.holidays[0].name : 'Não é feriado');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Data:</td>
    <td>
      <input dia value="21">/
      <input mes value="04">/
      <input ano value="2016">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Local:</td>
    <td>
      <select pais>
        <option value="BR">BR</option>
        <option value="US">US</option>
        <option value="FR">FR</option>
        <option value="ES">ES</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



<button>VERIFICAR</button>
```

Para PHP pode usar o cURL:

```
   function verificarFeriado($data, $boolean = false) {

    $param = array();

    // Sua chave (exigida após 01/08/2016!), leia no final dessa postagem!
    $param['key'] = '';

    // Listas de países suportados!
    $paisesSuportados = array('BE', 'BG', 'BR', 'CA', 'CZ', 'DE', 'ES', 'FR', 'GB', 'GT', 'HR', 'HU', 'ID', 'IN', 'IT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PR', 'SI', 'SK', 'US');

    // Define o pais para buscar feriados
    $param['country'] = $paisesSuportados[2];

    // Quebra a string em partes (em ano, mes e dia)
    list($param['year'], $param['month'], $param['day']) = explode('-', $data);

    // Converte a array em parâmetros de URL
    $param = http_build_query($param);

    // Conecta na API
    $curl = curl_init('https://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?'.$param);

    // Permite retorno
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Obtem dados da API
    $dados = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);

    // Encerra curl
    curl_close($curl); 

    // Retorna true/false se houver $boolean ou Nome_Do_Feriado/false se não houve $boolean
    return isset($dados['holidays']['0']) ? $boolean ? true : $dados['holidays']['0']['name'] : false;

    }

    var_export( verificarFeriado('2016-04-21') );
    // Resposta: 'Tiradentes'

    var_export( verificarFeriado('2016-04-21', true) );
    // Resposta: true

    var_export( verificarFeriado('2016-04-20') );
    // Resposta: false

    var_export( verificarFeriado('2016-04-20', true) );
    // Resposta: false
```

**Importante:**

> A partir do dia 01/08/2016 será necessário obter uma chave para a API,
>   para isso gere uma, gratuitamente, através do próprio site:
>   https://holidayapi.com/.
>
> A partir do dia 01/08/2016 será necessário usar o HTTPS ao invés do
>   HTTP.

> **A função (em PHP) foi atualizada no dia 12/07/2016 para suportar essas alterações da API.**

Answer (score -4):

```
function mod_date($str){
    
    $addtime = new DateTime($str);
    $data_pre = $addtime->format('N');
    
    if(!in_array($data_pre, array(6,7))){
        
        return $addtime->format('Y-m-d');
        
    } elseif($data_pre == 6){
        
        $addtime->modify('+2 days');
        return $addtime->format('Y-m-d');
        
    } elseif($data_pre == 7){
        
        $addtime->modify('+1 day');
        return $addtime->format('Y-m-d');
        
    }
    
}
```

Obtendo a próxima data utilizando a função acima:

```
echo mod_date('2022-08-20');
// Retorna: 2022-08-22
```