# Saber que dia cai a próxima segunda-feira

Tags: php, data

Preciso de uma programação para uma agenda que me de a data das próximas segunda-feiras a partir de uma determinada data

Ex: hoje e dia 01/06
Preciso saber que dia cairá as próximas 10 segundas feiras.

```
1 = 05/06/2017
2 = 12/06/2017
3 = 19/06/2017
4 = 26/06/2017
5 = 03/07/2017
6 = 10/07/2017
8 = 17/07/2017
9 = 24/07/2017
10= 31/07/2017
```

Meu problema esta em saber qual a próxima segunda a partir de uma determinada data, pois as próximas sera mais fácil e só somar os 7 dias

Comment: Também pode usar a mesma lógica dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111656/91)

Comment: Você poderia melhor o título para "Algoritmo para descobrir próxima segunda" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segue o código de exemplo para a próxima segunda-feira a partir de uma data:

```
$dia = new DateTime( '2017-06-01' );
$dia->modify( 'next monday' );

echo $dia->format('d/m/Y'); // 05/06/2017
```

[Link para visualizar o teste](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ce150a5f5474887bc83295126679543596010a4)

Pegar as 10 próximas segundas em um array a partir da próxima segunda pegando como referência o dia atual:

```
$dia = new DateTime();
$dia->modify( 'next monday' );

$nextMondaysNeed = range(1,10);
$nextMondaysArray = array($dia->format('Y-m-d'));

foreach($nextMondaysNeed as $number)
{
    $nextMondaysArray[] = $dia->modify('+7 day')->format('Y-m-d');
}

print_r($nextMondaysArray);
```

[Segue link de visualização.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca289cfd26f5142d06a2a10460c8c8e65af8ac01)

Comment: Olá Bruno, um plus na sua resposta seria em vez de adicionar uma data fixa para HOJE, poderia colocar `$dia = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', time()));`

Comment: Olá Everson, obrigado. No caso de pegar a data atual, você pode simplesmente deixar como new DateTime(). Não precisa informar valores, o próprio PHP seta a data como a atual.

Comment: Creio que ele queira as próximas 10 segundas e não "a proxima", fora que ele precisa somar

Comment: @Bruno Rigolon - Muito obrigado, a vc e ao Everson!

Comment: @BrunoRigolon entendi. Olhei a documentação e você realmente está correto! O construtor da classe seta por padrão a data atual ( `public __construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )`)

Comment: Gilherme, achando a próxima fica mais fácil, assim eu ja consigo somar com a quantidade que vou precisar aqui, minha questão principal era esta, saber qual seria a próxima segunda!

Answer (score 1):

Se você usa alguma versão do php menor que 5.3, use strtotime() :

```
$dataStr = "2010-11-24";
$timestamp = strtotime($dataStr);
echo date("d", $timestamp);
```

Se você usa uma versão maior ou igual à 5.3, podes usar isto :

```
$string = "2010-11-24";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $string);
echo $date->format("d");
```

Ref : [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275599/how-to-extract-only-day-value-from-full-date-string)

Comment: Sim, verdade. Acabei confundindo na escrita, valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Embora o autor já tenha uma resposta, vou colocar aqui minha contribuição para quem passar por problemas envolvendo lógica de programação no PHP.

**Dê nome aos bois..**

É muito comum programadores colocar nome de funções e variáveis estranhos, ou então palavras de outro idioma. Isso dificulta a solução de problemas, muitas vezes do próprio autor do código. Então sempre que possível, troque `$x` por `$quantidadeAtual` ... etc. Muitas vezes o código pode ficar mais extenso, mas a solução de problemas e erros ficam muito mais fáceis de identificar, por causa da boa escrita, que gera uma boa leitura.

**Pense procedural**

Muitas vezes, um problema por não ser bem definido, aparenta ser um problema de programação (recursos da linguagem, sintaxe, funções nativas) e não é. Pense que você é um pintor, e os recursos da linguagem são sua paleta de cores. Talvez você só precise ser um pouco criativo para resolver um problema, e não necessariamente recursos ou conhecimento adicional. Salvo casos em que você não domina a 'paleta' completamente, o que é o básico. Algumas funções do PHP retornam em strings, o que pode dificultar sua vida as vezes. No final desse post, vou mostrar que é possível resolver esse problema em especial, sem usar as funções nativas de datas. O que mostra que você não é preso a nenhum método de desenvolvimento, e que tem 'n' formas de resolver um problema. Um exercício bom, é enumerar num papel (papel mesmo de verdade), quais etapas você faria para solucionar determinado problema. Isso em linguagem natural mesmo! Nada de PHP, C#, JAVA.. O bom português mesmo.

**Não siga receita de bolo**

Nem mesmo esse post é uma receita de bolo. Existem situações que você escreverá a variável com nomes estranhos; sairá implementando sem uma estratégia; colocará loops do tipo  `[$j][$i][$m]` ou pior...e todos esses casos, pelo menos em algum momento serão situações dignas de explicação. Alguém pode querer manter um código curto de um laço, ter copiado e colado código, ou usado classe alheia, etc. O ponto aqui é, lógica de programação é sempre o caminho, independente do seu método de implementar. Segue solução proposta, com **exemplos extremos opostos**:

```
<?php header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$limiteDoMes = 31; // Essa linha estabelece um limite de dias para o mês
$agenda = array(12, 13, 17, 21, 29); // Array que guarda todos os dias agendados

$diasAgendados = count($agenda); // Conta quantos dias tem agendado, para aplicação saber quantas vezes terá que fazer sua tarefa até parar

$diasCorridos = 0; // Estabelece uma partida para a tarefa ser realizada
    while ($diasCorridos < $diasAgendados) // Enquanto (while) a quantidade de dias corrigos na análise, for menor que a quantidade de dias agendados, faça a tarefa abaixo
    {
        $proximaSegunda = $agenda[$diasCorridos] + 7; // Calcula a proxima segunda de cada dia agendado
        $segundaDoMesSeguinte = $agenda[$diasCorridos] + 7 - $limiteDoMes; // Calcula a proxima segunda se cair no mês seguinte

        if ($proximaSegunda > $limiteDoMes) // Se a próxima segunda cair no mês seguinte, escreva esse texto
        {
            echo "A próxima segunda feira depois do dia $agenda[$diasCorridos] será no mês seguinte, do dia $segundaDoMesSeguinte ";
        }
            else{ // Caso contrário, se cair neste mês, escreva isso
                echo "A próxima segunda feira depois do dia $agenda[$diasCorridos] será $proximaSegunda<br>";

            }
        $diasCorridos++; // Depois da tarefa executada, adicione 1, a dias corrigos, e faça a tarefa de novo, como uma roleta
    }

    ?>
```

Versão da mesma solução em codificação tradicional

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$lm     = 31;
$agenda = array(12,13,17,21,29); 

$da = count($agenda); 

$dc = 0; 
while ($dc < $da) 
                {
                $ps  = $agenda[$dc] + 7; 
                $sms = $agenda[$dc] + 7 - $lm;  seguinte

                if ($ps > $lm) 
                                {
                                echo "A próxima segunda feira depois do dia $agenda[$dc] será no mês seguinte, do dia $sms ";
                } else { 
                                echo "A próxima segunda feira depois do dia $agenda[$dc] será $ps<br>";

                }
                $dc++; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seque forma que funciona em mais linguagens de programação.

```
// 1 SEGUNDA 
// 2 TERCA 
// 3 QUARTA 
// 4 QUINTA 
// 5 SEXTA 
// 6 SABADO 
// 7 DOMINGO

$diaDaSemana = 3; // ALTERE PELO DIA DA SEMANA DA DATA
$xx = (1 - diaDaSemana + 7) % 7;
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.$xx.' days', strtotime('14-07-2014')));// ALTERE 14-07-2017 pela data a ser adicionado os dias
```

date é a proxima segunda feira.
 caso queira a proxima terça altere

```
  $xx = (1 - diaDaSemana + 7) % 7;
```

por

```
  $xx = (**2** - diaDaSemana + 7) % 7;
```

Comment: em qualquer linguagem, NUNCA faça calculo de datas/horas/períodos na mão, com certeza a sua linguagem já tem algo pronto. Alem do mais, não são todos os países que a semana começa na segunda :o)

Comment: Neste caso você consegue informar o primeiro dia da semana:'   public static int Dow(this DateTime date, DayOfWeek startDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            return (date.DayOfWeek - startDayOfWeek + 7) % 7 + 1;
        }'

Comment: Concordo que a maioria das linguagem já tem algo pronto